# GDB: debugging closed code

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I´m working with an application (closed sources, i don´t have the sources) that allows me to plug in my customizations developed in c (my own code, i have the sources) that are called by the main process via call backs, it like to have plugins.

When we try to debug the execution of this program, it fails trying to get the sources of the main program, as its closed source i don´t have it.

how can i debug this program? how can i configure gdb avoiding that it tries to retrieve the closed sources?

i´m working on hp-ux and i want to find memory leaks in my code.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you build your code with debug information, you should be able to use tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find memory problems in your code. And in GDB, once your code is loaded you should be able to e.g. set breakpoints in it as normal.

Comment: Yes the code is compiled with debug information and i can set the breakpoint, but the execution never arrives to that point as previously the program executes the closed code, and gdb fails to to get that sources.

Comment: And you're sure that the code in question is called?

Comment: Need more information. How is your 'plugin' is called? Is it shared library that being loaded at runtime? How (and when) you setting breakpoints? Usually you should be able to set breakpoint after library is loaded.

Comment: Why is not having sources for first closed-source part should not interfere with your debugging goal. Just start that application, determine a point where your extensions are loaded (probably shared library or something?), then put a breakpoint to one of your functions and continue...

Comment: Regarding: And you're sure that the code in question is called? The answer is yes, i can see it´s output when i execute it without gbd.

Comment: Regarding: Need more information. How is your 'plugin' is called? Is it shared library that being loaded at runtime? How (and when) you setting breakpoints? Usually you should be able to set breakpoint after library is loaded.  The answer is that my plugin is a shared library, that is being loaded at program startup, but before load my library it loads closed libraries and fails because tries to get .c file from that closed libraies.

Answer (score 1):

> When we try to debug the execution of this program, it fails trying to get the sources of the main program, as its closed source i don´t have it.

This is just a *warning* from GDB; one you can safely ignore.

> how can i debug this program?

The usual way. Debugging will be harder because you can't see the main application sources, but (assuming you only care about debugging your own code) not *too* hard.

> how can i configure gdb avoiding that it tries to retrieve the closed sources?

You can't, but it's not an error, and shouldn't prevent you from doing anything.